# Can't parse String to File in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, error-handling, compiler-errors

This is basic script where you input a file as one of the arguments and based on it's extension it executes it with a different program.
This is not the full code this just the code that is giving me an error:

```kotlin
package com.pavlos.efstathiou.runScript

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.File
import java.util.logging.Level.parse

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val filename: Any = args[0]
    if (args.isEmpty()) println("No arguments provided")
    if (args.size > 2) println("Too many arguments provided")
    fun read() {
        val filenameString = File.parse(filename) // I don't know what function to use to parse the filename String
        val reader: BufferedReader = filenameString.bufferedReader()
        val inputString = reader.use { it.readText() }
        println("Contents of file: $inputString")

    }
}
```

The only problem is that I can't parse the function's argument which is a String to a file name.
Sorry for the bad code I am a beginner in Kotlin

Comment: Is not working because you need the full path to the directory, create a file, and hardcode the full path, if it works is because of that.

Comment: @cutiko The filename is one of the arguments in the main function. I don't want to hardcode it I want to input it as one of the arguments

Comment: @cutiko runSript.kt:13:35: error: unresolved reference: parse
        val filenameString = File.parse(filename)

Comment: Im not saying keep it hardcoded as a in production, Im saying hardcoded so you can reduce the error to a single cause. Im showing you one way of debugging your problem. Hardcode it and if it doesnt fail then you know why. Next step is getting the project directory programatically. The file name is not the same than the file path. Otherwise, if it keep failling then there is other the problem

Comment: @cutiko Thanks but my problem is that I can't parse the file name to a string. I have searched for answers but I can't find any. It seems that no one has had my problem

Comment: @cutiko This a temporary fix:

Comment: What are you talking about? The arguments are strings, why do you need to parse a string to a string? You are using `BufferedReader` so you want to read the content of the file, right? Again, the file name is not the same as the file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll kick yourself…  :-)

To create a [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object, you simply call its [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-), e.g. `File("/path/to/myFile")`.  (There are other constructors which let you specify a directory and a filename separately, or a URI.)

A File is an abstract representation of the filename; it can be absolute (starting with `/` or whatever the root of your filesystem is), or relative (to the current directory).  The file doesn't even need to exist.

Of course, if not, then you'll get an error when you try to create a reader for it in the following line.  (You *will* be handling I/O errors when you convert that into production code, I'm sure!)

Kotlin provides other ways to read a file; take a look at extension functions like [File.useLines](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/use-lines.html), [File.readLines](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-lines.html), and [File.forEachLine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/for-each-line.html) which make it even easier.

Comment: I found a solution now. Thanks for the support!